# Non-operator equivalent to bpy.ops.uv.smart_project() available?

Tags: python, scripting, uv

I am using a script that is heavily relying upon `bpy.ops.uv.smart_project()`. I got the impression that the function has a big impact on performance, so I was wondering if there was an equivalent that is no operator (which might be faster in turn as it does not have anything to do with the UI).

Comment: As far as I know, operators called from scripts don't invoke the UI at all (unless you explicitly make the few that support this to do it). So if you feel that you have performance issues with this operator, it's probably simply because it performs heavy calculations. You might want to try find another way to achieve the same goals with less resource intensive methods.